# PHP Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, mysqli

I've seen this question before but all the solutions do not work for me. The main solution is to store the result which I already do. Most people say I am running 2 simultaneous queries which I don't understand. I may have used this function below more than once but I always free and close the statement so not sure why this is happening.

You can most likely ignore the top half of the function which just generates a string to represent the types. This is the full DB class I made:

(I edited it since I originally posted it and replaced self::$connection with self::$db)

```
class DB {
    private static $dbhost = "localhost";
    private static $dbuser = "some_user"; // placeholder
    private static $dbpass = "some_assword"; // placeholder
    private static $dbname = "database_name"; // placeholder
    private static $db;

    public static function connect() {          
        self::$db = new mysqli(self::$dbhost,  self::$dbuser, self::$dbpass, self::$dbname);        
        if (self::$db->connect_errno) {
            die("Database mysqli failed: " .
                self::$db->connect_error . " (" . 
                self::$db->connect_errno . ")"      
            );
        }
    }

    // IGNORE THIS! It just formats the parameters for the 
    // call_user_func_array function to work correctly.
    private static function getBindings(&$params) {
        $types = "";        
        $bindings = array();
        foreach ($params as $value) {
            switch (gettype($value)) {
                case "integer":
                    $types .= "i";
                    break;
                case "double":
                    $types .= "d";
                    break;
                case "string":
                    $types .= "s";
                    break;
                default: 
                    $types .= "s";
                    break;
            }
        }       
        foreach($params as $key => $value)
            $bindings[$key] = &$params[$key]; // assign to references (because bind_param requires references)      
        // to add a string of variable types to the start of the $bindings array (such as 'sss')
        array_unshift($bindings, $types);
        return $bindings;
    }

    public static function query($query, $params) {
        if (!isset(self::$db)) { self::connect(); }

        if (empty($params)) {
            // prepared statement not needed
            return self::$db->query($query);
        }

        $successful = false;
        $bindings = self::getBindings($params);

        // MySQL prepared statement execution:
        $statement = self::$db->prepare($query);
        call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), $bindings);       
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result(); 

        if ($statement->num_rows > 0) {
            // for select queries
            $successful = $statement->get_result(); // does not work! (returns boolean)

            echo self::$db->errno; // 2014          
            echo "<br />";
            echo self::$db->error; // Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
            echo "<br />";      

            // this method works fine (but I need to return the result set!):
            /*$name = false; $link = false;
            $statement->bind_result($name, $link);

           while ($statement->fetch()) {
                echo 'name: '.$name.'<br>';
                echo 'link: '.$link.'<br>';
           }*/
        } else if ($statement->affected_rows > 0) {
            // for insert queries
            $successful = true;
        }       

        $statement->free_result();
        $statement->close();
        return $successful;
    }

    public static function close() {
        if (isset(self::$db)) self::$db->close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is what one of my requests looks like (I have queried 2 requests on this same page using my DB class and DB::query(...) function):

```
$result = DB::query("SELECT * FROM table_name;");
if ($result) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // do stuff                             
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that you use both `store_result` and `get_result`?

Comment: @ethrbunny No I don't think so. The documentation says you need to store it first and then get_result just retrieves what was stored.

Comment: [mysqli - get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) - "Call to return a result set from a prepared statement query"

Comment: Yeah but it returns nothing unless you first store it. store_result says:

"You must call mysqli_stmt_store_result() for every query that successfully produces a result set"

and "Transfers a result set from a prepared statement". store_result returns only a boolean value to mark whether it was successful or not, not a result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the love of what is sane, change your driver to PDO and make all this code into

```
public static function query($query, $params = NULL)
{
    if (!$params) {
        return self::$connection->query($query);
    }

    $statement = self::$connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($params);
    return $statement;
}
```

to be used like this

```
$result = DB::query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
foreach($result as  $row) {
    // do stuff                             
}
```

Comment: That might help. Still learning PHP so never looked into PDO, I had better learn it :S

Comment: Excellent, but could you explain why this would solve the issue and what they were doing wrong?

Comment: @HenryTK definitely, it can't be that mysqli is just bugged for everyone. I'm closing and freeing the results like you're suppose to and have no clue why this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

The MySQL documentation regarding [Commands out of sync](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) suggest two possibilities:

1. You have used a result and are trying to execute a new query before freeing the last result.
2. You are running two queries (not necessarily simultaneously) without using or storing the result between each one.

The logic in your code shows the only situation where you are not freeing results is when no prepared statement is required. The answer to your problem may be to deal with this particular result and free or store it.

I can see from your code `self::$connection` is a static reference, therefore it could be possible that any query executed in that scope is using the same connection. It is hard to tell without being able to see your full class.

Comment: Yeah, I only connect to the database once using: 

self::$connection = mysqli_connect(self::$dbhost, 
   //self::$dbuser, self::$dbpass, self::$dbname);

But I thought you only needed to connect once and then can perform many queries and then close it?

Comment: Correct, you can perform many queries with the same connection. I had a theory that one of the queries you were doing may have not been a prepared statement, because you are returning at that point, therefore could be leaving a result set without storing or freeing it. How many queries are you running with that connection, and what are they?

Comment: I use 2 queries in the PHP page and use $result->free() which makes no difference. I also tried $result->close() and same result. If I use them both together then I get an error.

Comment: Whoever downvoted my answer please provide an explanation why. I like to actually learn from my mistakes, it's one of the best ways of learning.

Comment: It was not me, just for the record.

Comment: I uploaded my entire DB class and altered it slightly since last time so that I am using the complete OOP approach rather than some of it being procedural. I replaced self::$connection with self::$db as well.